# why yum-config-manager isnt part of rhel 7.6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, iso

we are using rhel 7.6 version

we are very surprised that yum-config-manager  isnt installed on rhel 7.6 by default

so we download the ISO file of rhel 7.6 , and mount all pkgs from rhel 7.6 to /mnt

and create the repo for rhel 7.6

so now we try to install the yum-config-manager

but:

```
yum install yum-config-manager
Loaded plugins: langpacks
configuration
No package yum-config-manager available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

so I not understand why this pkg/rpm isn't part of the ISO?

update , we did also

```
yum provides */yum-config-manager
Loaded plugins: langpacks
configuration
InstallMedia/filelists_db                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 MB  00:00:00

yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch : Utilities based around the yum package manager
Repo        : InstallMedia
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/yum-config-manager



yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch : Utilities based around the yum package manager
Repo        : @InstallMedia
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/yum-config-manager
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `yum-config-manager` program is not a standalone package. It is part of `yum-utils` package, thus:

```
yum install yum-utils
```

Comment: its strange because I have - yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch , but not yum-config-manager

Comment: Try reinstalling it, e.g. `yum reinstall yum-utils`. To make sure whether a given *installed* package provides the file you ned you can run: `rpm -ql yum-utils | grep config-manager`. To see which packages from the repos, provide the files you need you can also try `yum provides */yum-config-manager`

Comment: I did it but still not have yum-config-manager

Comment: see the update in my question

Comment: I can assure you it is part of the package.

Comment: but why subscription-manager
bash: subscription-manager: command not found. , ir should be part of yum-config-manager?

Comment: the main thing is that we want to use subscription-manager , in order to register redhat repo

Comment: But `subscription-manager` is a completely different package.

Comment: I was thinking that subscription-manager is part of yum-config-manager , so in that case , then why ISO file not include it?

Comment: @yael your questions claims you seek `yum-config-manager` which has little relation to subscription manager. If you want subscription manager, you need `subscription-manager` as mentioned by @jsbillings

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says, it’s part of the `yum-utils` package.  Any other missing package would most likely be on the supplementary binary DVD ISO. They can’t fit everything on an ISO that can be burned to a DVD.

If you are installing off a mounted ISO image and aren’t registering the system with redhat, why not just use the [Everything](http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/isos/x86_64/) ISO from CentOS?  It’d be easier to use.

Comment: its strange because I have - yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch , but not yum-config-manager

Comment: since you link that you gave is centos , then I guess yum-config-manager , it not part of any of the ISO files there , as you know yum-config-manager can activated only form tedhat OS

Comment: @yael no. It’s part of CentOS too.  In fact, it’s easier to prove because I can link to the package itself: http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch.rpm

Comment: I want to clear something , dose subscription-manager  is part of yum-config-manager

Comment: It isn’t part of `yum-utils` but in the aptly named package `subscription-manager`.

Comment: very strange because I have it - rpm -qa | grep yum-utils
yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch

Comment: so if 
yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch , is installed then why I not  have the cli - subscription-manager

Comment: What exactly do you want?  If you want to run subscription-manager, then install the subscription-manager package.  If you want yum-config-manager, install the yum-utils package.

Comment: You already know how to answer these questions. Use the `yum provides ....` query you used in your post.